# Android - reading local html as text file: differences between using InputStreamReader.read and BufferedReader.readLine

Tags: android, text, inputstream, innerhtml, bufferedreader

I have to read an html as a text file and I have implemented two different methods as described on SO threads. I clean the html leaving just the body content to put it into DOM with document.write(string) with both methods, but it only works if I use Bufferedreader.readLine() (appending a stringBuilder in a loop). In fact, if I print the stringBuilder.toString() in the Logcat window I see that when BufferedReader.readLine() is used the stringBuilder is displayed on a single line in the Logcat window, while with InputStreamReader.read(charArray,0,(int)numBytes) it is displayed multi-line (I am using a real device). Maybe this can be related and suggest which is the issue. My question is : how have I to clean or process that char Array read by read(charArray,0,(int)numBytes) to be the same of the stringBuilder appended in the readLine() loop?

Comment: You are aware that `BufferedReader#readLine()` does not include the line-termination characters when it returns the line? This is what causes you to get a "single line" logcat output - in effect you are **stripping** your HTML of \n (and \r) characters with this method. If you include any <pre/> sections or similar styles this will cause your HTML to render incorrectly.

Comment: thank you for this crucial suggestion, I think I have to ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method reads till the end of the line and returns the value  **excluding** the newline character. Hence when you append it to a `StringBuffer` everything gets appended to a single line.  However, in the case of [`InputStreamReader.read`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read%28char%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29), the newline character is also included, causing the string to be displayed in multiple lines.

To make the behavior similar, you will have to skip newline character while using `InputStreamReader.read`.

Comment: how can I process the StringBuilder to tear off the newline (one char or two? what chars? ASCII 13+10 or 10+13? just 10?)

Comment: Depends on the file that you read. To be generic, you can replace all occurrences of '\n', '\r' or "\r\n". Use `String.replace` method to achieve the result.

Comment: who is interested in this topic, attention please, read the suggestion from Jens as comment to my question.